# JFrame#setLayout(LayoutManager) not working. Forced to do getContentPane().setLayout(LayoutManager)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, contentpane

When running code that instantiates this class:

```
static final class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();

    public MyFrame() {
        setLayout(layout);
        System.out.println(getLayout());
    }
}
```

The results that are printed are:

```
java.awt.BorderLayout[hgap=0,vgap=0]
```

Which is `JFrame`s default layout. The layout is not changed. But, if I change

```
setLayout(layout);
```

to

```
getContentPane().setLayout(layout)
```

`getLayout()` will print the correct layout.

**MVCEs:**

Not setting layout:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    static final class MyFrame extends JFrame {
        private CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();

        public MyFrame() {
            setLayout(layout);
            System.out.println(getLayout());
        }
    }
}
```

Setting layout:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    static final class MyFrame extends JFrame {
        private CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();

        public MyFrame() {
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            System.out.println(getLayout());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does getContentPane().getLayout() also print different values ?

Comment: What version of Java

Comment: @MadProgrammer Version 8u60 @Berger `getContentPane().getLayout()` prints the correct layout, which makes sense. What doesn't make sense is that `getLayout()` only prints the correct layout if I set it via `getContentPane()`. (Sorry for the retag, accidentally deleted my comment)

Comment: What is printed please? This is strange because setLayout calls getContentPane().setLayout()

Comment: The second one does not print the correct layout...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're missing something somewhere. Here are the results on my pc using [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) and [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

```
setLayout(layout);
System.out.println(getContentPane().getLayout()); // CardLayout is printed
System.out.println(getLayout()); // BorderLayout is printed

getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
System.out.println(getContentPane().getLayout()); // CardLayout is printed
System.out.println(getLayout()); // BorderLayout is printed
```

---

### Why isn't CardLayout always printed?

Because, unlike [`JFrame#setLayout(LayoutManager)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JFrame.java#JFrame.setLayout%28java.awt.LayoutManager%29), `JFrame#getLayout()` does not make a call to its `contentPane()`.

As a matter of fact, `JFrame#getLayout()` is actually inherited from [`Container#getLayout()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Container.java#Container.getLayout%28%29) which will return the actual `LayoutManager` from the actual component (in this case `JFrame` and not its `contentPane()`).

---

### [`JFrame#setLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setLayout(java.awt.LayoutManager))

> Sets the LayoutManager. Overridden to conditionally forward the call
>   to the contentPane. Refer to RootPaneContainer for more information.